# How can I get only the hour or minute part from post request in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to receive only the hour part or minute part in django. Right now i'm using `remindTime = request.POST.get("remindTime")` to get the time but I only want the hour or minute or day or month. How can I do that?

here is the model

```
class Reminder(models.Model):
    remindTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
```

how I get the time

```
if request.method == "POST":
    remindTime = request.POST.get("remindTime")
```

Ty!

Comment: convert `remindTime` to a python datetime object